# Prove integer remains $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ after Division and Floor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given a positive integer $w$, let $r$ be an integer that satisfies: $r \in{} \{0,1,2, \ldots{}, 2^{w}-1 \}$, that is, $r \in{} \mathbb{Z}_{2^w}$.

I want to prove that:

> for any $p$, that $p \in{} \mathbb{Z}_{w}$. Let $t = \lfloor{}\frac{r}{2^{p}}\rfloor{}$, we have
> $t \in{}  \mathbb{Z}_{2^{w-p}}$

**For instance**, for $w=3$, we have $r \in{} \{0,1,2, \ldots{}, 7 \}$, then:

1. Suppose $p=1$, we have $t = \lfloor{}\frac{r}{2}\rfloor{}$, which means $t \in{} \{ 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3 \} = \{ 0,1,2,3 \}$, hence $t \in{}  \mathbb{Z}_{2^{2}}$.
2. Suppose $p=2$, we have $t = \lfloor{}\frac{r}{4}\rfloor{}$, which means $t \in{} \{ 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1 \} = \{ 0,1 \}$, hence $t \in{}  \mathbb{Z}_{2^{1}}$.

Things might be simple if treating $r$ as a binary number (i.e. from the perspective of *computer science*). But I prefer a completely mathematical proof, and just have no idea where to start it, seeking for help! Could anyone give some suggestions or hints? Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple exercise in inequality. No need to incorporate modular arithmetic. In particular, what you are asked to prove is that given any $0\le r\lt2^w$ and $0\le p<w$, we have:
$$
\lfloor \frac{r}{2^p} \rfloor\le\frac{r}{2^p}\lt\frac{2^w}{2^p}=2^{w-p}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! In fact,I have already known that range  before the post , and more concisely, is that $t \in{} [0,2^{w-p})$. What I cannot convince myself is that, $t \in{} [0,2^{w-p})$ doesn't mean $t$ gets a chance to hit every integer in the range $[0,2^{w-p})$. This is why I wrote the range of $t$ as $\mathbb{Z_{2^{w-p}}}$, which is **slightly** different from $[0,2^{w-p})$. Isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelLee Note that $t$ is an integer by the definition of the floor operator $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$.